# How to clear specific cache using cache key in Apigee

Tags: curl, apigee

> curl -v -H by-pass=true -u rsekhar@beachbody.com
>   'https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/beachbody/environments/test/caches/beachbodyCache/entries/beachbody__test__trainers-test-dev4-v1__default__apiProxyURI__/tony-horton?action=clear'
>   -X POST

I am generating key using proxy `proxy.pathsuffix` and `request.uri`

**Cache Key :** *beachbody__test__trainers-test-dev4-v1__default__apiProxyURI__/tony-horton*

Comment: Hi Guys, I got the answer for this. use '/' in encoded format that is %2F

curl -v -H by-pass=true -u rsekhar@beachbody.com 'https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/beachbody/environments/test/caches/beachbodyCache/entries/beachbody__test__trainers-test-dev4-v1__default__apiProxyURI__%2Ftony-horton?action=clear' -X POST

using this way we can clear specific cache from the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this. use '/' in encoded format that is %2F

Request:
curl -v -H by-pass=true -u rsekhar@beachbody.com 'https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/beachbody/environments/test/caches/beachbodyCache/entries/beachbody__test__trainers-test-dev4-v1__default__apiProxyURI__%2Ftony-horton?action=clear' -X POST

using this way we can clear specific Apigee cache from the terminal